(WoW Addon) Trying to display item upgrade costs in tooltip
Still nothing being displayed on the tooltip, seems to be an error with the ItemLocation, and C_Item.GetItemUpgradeItemInfo(ItemLocation) functions. the debugger would have to go just 2 or 3 more steps and it will be catching all the relevant information, then displaying it won't be too hard. Need a wow addon or lua expert to teach me where im going wrong

 -- Create the frame for handling events
    local frame = CreateFrame("Frame")
    
    -- Function to handle item tooltip display and upgrade cost
    local function OnTooltipSetItem(tooltip)
        local name, link = tooltip:GetItem()
        if not link then return end
    
        -- Print the item link for debugging
        print("Item Link:", link)
    
        -- Extract and print the item ID
        local itemID = tonumber(string.match(link, "item:(%d+)"))
        if not itemID then
            print("Failed to extract ItemID")
            return
        end
        print("Item ID:", itemID)
    
    -- Attempt to create an ItemLocation object using bag and slot information
    local itemLocation
    for bag = 0, NUM_BAG_SLOTS do
        for slot = 1, C_Container.GetContainerNumSlots(bag) do
            local slotItemID = C_Container.GetContainerItemID(bag, slot)
            if slotItemID == itemID then
                itemLocation = ItemLocation:CreateFromBagAndSlot(bag, slot)
                break
            end
        end
        if itemLocation then break end
    end
    
    if itemLocation then
        if itemLocation:IsValid() then
            print("Item Location is valid")
            local bag, slot = itemLocation:GetBagAndSlot()
            print("Bag:", bag, "Slot:", slot)
        else
            print("Item Location is not valid")
        end
    else
        print("ItemLocation object is nil")
    end
    
    
    -- Debug output for equipped items
    if itemLocation and itemLocation:IsValid() then
        if itemLocation:GetType() == "BAG" then
            local bag, slot = itemLocation:GetBagAndSlot()
            print("Bag:", bag, "Slot:", slot)
        elseif itemLocation:GetType() == "EQUIPMENT" then
            local equipmentSlot = itemLocation:GetEquipmentSlot()
            print("Equipment Slot:", equipmentSlot)
        end
    end
    
    
    -- If not found in bags, check equipped items
    if not itemLocation then
        for slot = 1, 19 do -- 19 equipment slots
            local slotItemID = GetInventoryItemID("player", slot)
            if slotItemID == itemID then
                itemLocation = ItemLocation:CreateFromEquipmentSlot(slot)
                break
            end
        end
    end
    
    if not itemLocation then
        print("Failed to create ItemLocation")
        return
    end
    
    -- Debug output for itemLocation
    print("Item Location:", itemLocation and itemLocation:IsValid() and "Valid" or "Invalid")
    print("Bag:", itemLocation and itemLocation:GetBagAndSlot() or "N/A")
    print("Slot:", itemLocation and itemLocation:GetBagAndSlot() or "N/A")
    
    -- Check if the item can be upgraded
    local isValid = C_ItemUpgrade.CanUpgradeItem(itemLocation)
    print("Can Upgrade:", isValid)
    if not isValid then
        return
    end
    
    -- Get the item upgrade info
    local itemUpgradeInfo = C_ItemUpgrade.GetItemUpgradeItemInfo(itemLocation)
    if not itemUpgradeInfo then
        print("Failed to get item upgrade info for item ID:", itemID)
        print("Item Location:", itemLocation and itemLocation:IsValid() and "Valid" or "Invalid")
        return
    end
    print("Item Upgrade Info:", itemUpgradeInfo)
    
    
        -- Check the current upgrade level and max upgrade level
        local currentUpgradeLevel = C_ItemUpgrade.GetItemUpgradeCurrentLevel(itemLocation)
        local maxUpgradeLevel = C_ItemUpgrade.GetItemUpgradeMaxLevel(itemLocation)
        print("Current Upgrade Level:", currentUpgradeLevel)
        print("Max Upgrade Level:", maxUpgradeLevel)
    
        -- Determine the current season
        local currentSeason = C_ItemUpgrade.GetCurrentItemUpgradeSeason()
        print("Current Season:", currentSeason)
    
        -- Determine the season index
        local seasonIndex = itemUpgradeInfo.upgradeCostTypesForSeasonIndex and itemUpgradeInfo.upgradeCostTypesForSeasonIndex[currentSeason]
        print("Season Index:", seasonIndex)
    
        -- Get the cost for the current season if available
        local cost = itemUpgradeInfo.upgradeCostTypesForSeason and itemUpgradeInfo.upgradeCostTypesForSeason[seasonIndex]
        if cost then
            print("Upgrade Cost:", cost)
            tooltip:AddDoubleLine("Upgrade Cost:", GetCoinTextureString(cost), 1, 1, 1)
        else
            print("No cost available for the current season")
        end
    end
    
    -- Function to handle ADDON_LOADED event
    local function OnAddonLoaded(self, event, addon)
        if addon == "UpgradeLion" then
            -- Register the tooltip hook
            if TooltipDataProcessor then
                -- For Dragonflight and later
                TooltipDataProcessor.AddTooltipPostCall(Enum.TooltipDataType.Item, OnTooltipSetItem)
            else
                -- For earlier versions
                GameTooltip:HookScript("OnTooltipSetItem", OnTooltipSetItem)
                ItemRefTooltip:HookScript("OnTooltipSetItem", OnTooltipSetItem)
            end
    
            -- Unregister the ADDON_LOADED event
            self:UnregisterEvent("ADDON_LOADED")
        end
    end
    
    -- Register the ADDON_LOADED event
    frame:RegisterEvent("ADDON_LOADED")
    frame:SetScript("OnEvent", OnAddonLoaded)
    

